With GitLab, getting "fatal: mismatched algorithms: client sha1; server sha256" error when running pipeline on fork
I have a CI pipeline which runs a basic Python unit test command. It uses the python:3.11 Docker base image.
When the pipeline runs in the main repo, everything works fine. However, when running the pipeline in a fork, I get the following error message.
Preparing environment
Running on runner-xxx-concurrent-0 via runner-xxx...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/<username>/<project_name>/.git
Created fresh repository.
fatal: mismatched algorithms: client sha1; server sha256
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I've confirmed that my repo, my local git, and all commits in the repo, are using SHA256 (in both the main repo and the fork).

the message states sha1 is used in the client. How did you check exactly that your git client was using sha256 ?

also, which git version is running on the docker image, and which is runnign on the server ?

I'm using GitLab.com, so I can't tell what version the "server" is using. The image appears to be using git v2.39.5 (via git --version, in the test step). It seems none of the core.repositoryformatversion nor extensions.objectFormat git configuration variables are set.
